# Compile a PHP script in Linux

Tags: php, linux

I know PHP scripts don't actually compile until they are run. However, say I want to create a small simple program and compile it to a binary without requiring the PHP binary. How could I do this?

I've seen a few IDE's out there that would do this, but either they are all for windows or the Linux versions don't actually build properly.
What I would like is something like py2exe that does it in the script itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [phc: the PHP compiler](https://github.com/pbiggar/phc)

If you just want to run it like a script, you may not need to compile it per se, but just run it via the command line.  [Read running PHP via the command line.](http://www.php.net/features.commandline)

Comment: "per se" please. I see this mistake more and more often: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per_se

Answer (score 4):

There is this: http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/ but that compiles to Windows bytecode.  There are a few others, but all I have seen will compile for windows only.
Few More:

http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm

Edit: I almost forgot if your looking to make it work on linux without regard for windows you can just add

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

to the top of the script and you should be able to run it from the command line.  Don't forget to chmod +x the file first.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Facebook's [Hiphop-PHP](http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php#readme). It's able to convert PHP code into C++ then compile it with g++. Apparently, they've even gotten it to successfully compile entire WordPress installations.